# when assigning case to another user getting error msg

Tags: case

when assigning case to another user getting error msg

> change of ownership failed because current user has no sharing access
> to parent account

but system admin can assign cases to other user even new user do not have access to parent account of that case.

Answer (score 0):

The user performing the transfer of the case, either to themselves, or to another user, must also be able to access the account the case belongs to. This error has nothing to do with the recipient of the case's permissions on the account. The administrator can obviously view all records, so there's no problem when they transfer the case. However, they should be aware that they may be granting access to an account the user shouldn't be able to see otherwise (known as "implicit sharing"). This rule is in place so that a user can't "share" an account to a user accidentally.

Comment: @sfdcox i tried after assigning a permission set wit view all and edit permission for both account and case, still facing the same error

Comment: @Sfdcox thanks it solved my problem